# window.Connection on Chrome using ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying t. heo check if network connection is exist or not. here is some code

```
 if (window.Connection) {
        if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("connectionType", '0');
        } else {
            window.localStorage.setItem("connectionType", '1');
        }
    } else {
        alert("function doesnot run");
    }
```

It is working fine on device and emulator. Can we check same on web browser

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question is `navigator.onLine`. It returns true if you are connected to some network..

Here's a snap from my browser

[image]